# Remove multiple lines from file using PHP

Tags: php

I have been searching for a number of hours now for a solution to remove a block of text within a file using PHP script.

There appears to be a number of options for removing lines of text, but not a block of text. I have attempted to use `preg_replace ("/^$start.*?$end/s", $replace, $fdata)` with the following, but have not found a solution that works.

I am sure that someone has done this already, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
$start = "# Copyright 2000-";
$end = "Agreement.";

# This software product may only be used strictly in accordance
# with the applicable written License Agreement.
```

Comment: Is this software you're writing? Or software you're trying to steal?

Comment: Now matt let's give him the benefit of the doubt, he could be open sourcing his own software, or updating a licence for software he or his company wrote.

Comment: Not stealing the software, but was updating the source code for my companies product...we ship source code and it's a requirement to have the copyright statement. Thanks VoroniPatato

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [multi-line mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (`/m`), otherwise your regex won't capture across multiple lines. Also, you should escape your regex parameters with [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote), otherwise you may get undesired results (for example, in `$end`, it has a dot, which is a regex metacharacter, when you want it to match a single period.)

```
$regex = "/^" . preg_quote( $start, '/') .".*?". preg_quote( $end, '/') . "/sm";
preg_replace ( $regex, $replace, $fdata);
```